# Django serializer get related field

Tags: django

I have a querySet that I want to turn into a json and send to the client.
It only needs some of the fields, as defined.
However, the 'sender' shows up as a `id` because it is a `foreignKey`.

What would be needed to return the senders `username` instead? (`sender.username` didn't work). (Not using drf)

```
messages = Message.objects.all()
messages_json = serializers.serialize("json", messages, fields=('id','sender', 'text', 'timestamp'))
```

Comment: first serialize sender and then replace that data with 'sender' field in Message.If you are using DRF take a look at model serializer and SerializerMethodField

Comment: Are you using django rest?

Comment: django serialisers aren't really well suited for this. If you don't use DRF, you should consider using it, if only for the serialisers it provides. Otherwise you have to write this yourself.

Comment: @Stargazer as mentioned, not using DRF.  @JibinMathews, not sure what you mean there , or how that could work. Would that require 2 queries? seems inefficient, because the data is already somehow available in this `messages` queryset

Comment: @Alex it's not in the QuerySet unless you change to `messages = Message.objects.all().select_related('sender')`. When looping through messages, accessing msg.sender.name will not perform an additional query.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but using `QuerySet.values` and `__` relations-walking lets you get the data in one hit:

```
import json

messages = Message.objects.all()
payload_data = messages.values('id', 'sender__username', 'text', 'timestamp')

# tidy up the dict key names, assuming the client needs that doing
for x in payload_data:
    x['sender'] = x['sender__username']
    del x['sender__username']

messages_json = json.dumps(payload_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a way so I'll answer it myself

```
from django.core.serializers.python import Serializer

class MySerialiser(Serializer):
    def end_object( self, obj ):
        self._current['username'] = obj.sender.username
        self.objects.append(self._current)

serializer = MySerialiser()
messages_ser  = serializer.serialize(messages, fields=('id','sender','text' ))
messages_json = json.dumps(messages_ser)
```

`messages_ser` is a orderedDict, so turning it into json only works when there are no nested objects/dicts